# Table sort on two columns

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am having some trouble finding a solution to a table sort issue.

My table is essentially a file directory:

```
Name          FileSize    FileType
folder1/      -           folder
folder2/      -           folder
abc.pdf       3.2MB       pdf
def.jpg       1.2MB       jpg
ghi.doc       1.5MB       doc
```

I would like for the directories to stay at the top of the table no matter which column is sorted. For example, sorting on "Name" would sort the directories by name, then the files by name. Basically, all sorts need to first sort on FileType with "folders" being the top value, then by name or filesize.

I had been using the infamous "Frequency-Decoder" sort script, but would welcome another script should it make it any easier.

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery tablesorter plugin is just for you.

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

with this plugin you can disable some things to be shorted

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-headers.html

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding it correctly, but I don't see how disabling one column, will achieve the scenario explained above. can you clarify this?

Comment: this plugin has so many options and you can even add your codes in it and make it work like you wish. if you want to short something and at the same time you don't want short something you can use jquery and this plugin is just does what it does.

Answer (score 0):

For each folder name add the string String.fromCharCode(0) to the front these will always be alphabetically before any other string but will be displayed as just the name.

eg

```
String.fromCharCode(0)+"folder1/";
String.fromCharCode(0)+"folder2/";
```

Do becareful in any comparisons though as

String.fromCharCode(0)+"folder1/" is not equal to "folder1/"

Answer (score 0):

What do you say about that?
The sort script checks if the object is a folder, put it at the top, then process the actual sorting (folder with folder and file with file).

```
var files = [
  {
    name    : 'folder2/',
    filesize: null,
    filetype: 'folder'
  },
  {
    name    : 'folder1/',
    filesize: null,
    filetype: 'folder'
  },
  {
    name    : 'def.jpg',
    filesize: '1.2',
    filetype: 'jpg'
  },
  {
    name    : 'abc.pdf',
    filesize: '3.2',
    filetype: 'pdf'
  },
  {
    name    : 'ghi.doc',
    filesize: '1.5',
    filetype: 'doc'
  },
  {
    name    : 'jkl.doc',
    filesize: '1.1',
    filetype: 'doc'
  },
  {
    name    : 'pqr.pdf',
    filesize: '3.5',
    filetype: 'pdf'
  },
  {
    name    : 'mno.pdf',
    filesize: '3.5',
    filetype: 'pdf'
  }
];

/**
 * Sort an array of files and always put the folders at the top.
 * @access public
 * @param  {Array} array to sort
 * @param  {String} column to sort
 * @param  {Bool} asc
 * @return void
 */
function sortBy(array, column, asc) {
  if (asc == null) {
    asc = true;
  }

  array.sort(function(a, b) {

    // Put at the top the folders.
    if (a.filetype == 'folder' && b.filetype != 'folder') {
      return false;

    // Sort between folders.
    // The folders don't have a filesize and the type is always the same.
    // Process as a sort by name.
    // It doesn't need to respect the sens of sorting.
    } else if ((column == 'filesize' || column == 'filetype') && a.filetype == 'folder' && b.filetype == 'folder') {
      return a.name > b.name;

    // Normal sort.
    // The folders will be sorted together and the files togethers.
    } else {
      return asc ? a[column] > b[column] : a[column] < b[column];
    }

  });
}

sortBy(files, 'name', false);
console.log('by name', files);

sortBy(files, 'filesize', true);
console.log('by size', files);

sortBy(files, 'filetype', false);
console.log('by type', files);
```